# Regex to remove popular email domains like gmail, hotmail for user signup

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I basically want new user to only sign up via company emails now that might be a bit impossible with all the options so I was just thinking of using regex to do a match check on the top 15 emails (https://email-verify.my-addr.com/list-of-most-popular-email-domains.php) gmail, yahoo, hotmai, aol. Does anyone have a regex for this?

Comment: Why do you not just check if the company domain is included?

Comment: @gmail.com is also a company domain and its not specific to one domain anyone can signup we just want it not to be gmail, hotmail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of regex, you can consider writing a function like this.

```
List<String> top15Domains = ['gmail.com', 'yahoo.com'];

bool isValidEmail(String email){
  int index = email.indexOf('@');
  if(index == -1){
    return false;
  }
  String domain = email.substring(index + 1);
  return !top15Domains.contains(domain);
}
```

Comment: Thanks not sure why I did not think of that

Answer (score 0):

A simple Regex would be checking for a match in the ending of the email address.

```
@(hotmail.com|gmail.com)$
```

You would need to exclude any emails that match this pattern. Add email domains separated by a |. The $ sign signifies that the Regex searches for the ending of the word. Make sure you Trim() the address from white-space characters in the end.

Note: This Regex Code is case sensitive so make sure you set the email ToLower() or run Regex in case insensitive mode(depending of the language you are using).

You can test your regex in various sites. https://regexr.com is the one i am currently using